# need to ajaxify my code

Tags: php, ajax

i need to ajaxify  this code and remove header location option in php. i want the user remain on same page after clicking add to cart button  .....any help is highly appreciated
My javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function addtocart(pid){
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add';
    document.form1.submit();
}
</script>


<?php 
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
    $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
    addtocart($pid,1);
    header("location:shoppingcart.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

displaying products

```
<form name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>

<?php echo $row['picture']?>" />
<b><?php echo $row['name']?></b><br />
<?php echo $row['description']?><br />
Price:<big style="color:green">
$<?php echo $row['price']?></big><br /><br />
<input type="button" 
value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row['serial']?>)" />
```

part of my shopping cart

```
<?php 

if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
else if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{ $msg='Some proudcts
        not updated!, quantity must be a number  
         between 1 and 999';
        }
    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Other than that the PHP self submission aspects will need to be moved to a separate PHP page and handled as the response data for the success event of the ajax request

Comment: You should split up your JS and PHP code into different files and not try to mix the code like you do. You will then use AJAX calls to load the required elements in combination with PHP backend scripts to i.e. display a cart's contents etc. If you need help with detail questions (and not asking to rewrite your shopping system for you), come back and create a new topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what I've put together. You'll need to make a few changes as to the URL in the ajax part, how the return data is handled.
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzzcdsa7/

Code:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" id="productid" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" id="command" name="command" />
</form>

function addtocart(pid){
    $("#productid").val(pid);
    $("#command").val('add');
    ajaxSubmit();
}
function ajaxSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mypage.php",
        data: {"productid": $("#productid").val(), "command": $("#command").val()},
        success: function(returnedData) {
             alert(returnedData);   
        }
    });   
}
addtocart(12); // addtocart( _ ID _ );
```

Comment: Mr Scott Powell  your solution worked like charm as i had  to do some figuring out myself. i dont have words to explain my joy Sir thank you very much your help is highly appreciated Sir